# How to use others contracts in main contract?

Tags: contract-design

I have two protected contracts, they are:

```
_ Candidate
_ Elector
```

They're just using it to redirect their logic, as if they're "abstract";

And I have the main contract: `ElectronicVotingMachine`

In it, I need to apply those “abstract contracts”.

However, I'm using the reserved word "`new`", and when I give `console` I get a memory address and not the contract object itself, as if it were a struct.

**What is the correct way to do it?**

**CANDIDATE**

```
contract _Candidate {
    uint private _id;
    string private _avatar;

    constructor(uint id, string memory avatar) {
        _id = id;
        _avatar = avatar;
    }

    function getInformation() external view returns (uint, string memory) {
        return (_id, _avatar);
    }
}
```

**ELECTOR**

```
enum VoteType {
    CONFIRMED,
    ABSTENTION,
    DID_NOT_VOTED
}

contract _Elector {
    address private _wallet;
    VoteType private _vote = VoteType.DID_NOT_VOTED;

    constructor(address wallet, VoteType vote) {
        _wallet = wallet;
        _vote = vote;
    }

    function getInformation() external view returns (address, VoteType) {
        return (_wallet, _vote);
    }
}
```

**ELECTRONIC VOTING MACHINE**

```
import "./_Candidate.sol";
import "./_Elector.sol";

struct Vote {
    uint total;
    uint totalPercentage;
}

struct PollingByCandidate {
    _Candidate candidate;
    _Elector[] electors;
    Vote votes;
}

contract ElectronicVotingMachine {
    PollingByCandidate[6] private _pollingByCandidate;
    Vote private _abstentionVotes;
    uint private _totalElectoresVoted;

    constructor() {
        _abstentionVotes.total = 0;
        _abstentionVotes.totalPercentage = 0.00;
        _totalElectoresVoted = 0;

        _startPolling(0, "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thiagosaud/dApp-superior-electoral-court/main/temp/imgs/candidate-1.png");
        _startPolling(1, "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thiagosaud/dApp-superior-electoral-court/main/temp/imgs/candidate-2.png");
        _startPolling(2, "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thiagosaud/dApp-superior-electoral-court/main/temp/imgs/candidate-3.png");
        _startPolling(3, "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thiagosaud/dApp-superior-electoral-court/main/temp/imgs/candidate-4.png");
        _startPolling(4, "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thiagosaud/dApp-superior-electoral-court/main/temp/imgs/candidate-5.png");
        _startPolling(5, "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thiagosaud/dApp-superior-electoral-court/main/temp/imgs/candidate-6.png");
    }

    function getPollingByCandidates() external view returns (PollingByCandidate[6] memory) {
        return _pollingByCandidate;
    }

    function getAbstentionVotes() external view returns (Vote memory) {
        return _abstentionVotes;
    }

    function getTotalElectoresVoted() external view returns (uint) {
        return _totalElectoresVoted;
    }

    function _startPolling(uint candidateId, string memory candidateAvatar) public {
        _pollingByCandidate[candidateId].candidate = new _Candidate(candidateId, candidateAvatar);
        _pollingByCandidate[candidateId].votes = Vote({total: 0, totalPercentage: 0.0});
    }

    function _calculePercentageOfVote(uint totalVotes) private view returns (uint) {
        return ((totalVotes / _totalElectoresVoted) * 100);
    }

    function _updateTotalElectoresVoted() private {
        _totalElectoresVoted += 1;
    }

    function updateAbstentionVotes() external {
        _updateTotalElectoresVoted();

        _abstentionVotes.total += 1;
        _abstentionVotes.totalPercentage = _calculePercentageOfVote(_abstentionVotes.total);
    }

    function updateConfirmedVotes(
        uint candidateId,
        address electorWallet,
        VoteType electorVoteType
    ) external {
        _updateTotalElectoresVoted();

        _pollingByCandidate[candidateId].votes.total += 1;
        _pollingByCandidate[candidateId].electors.push(new _Elector({wallet: electorWallet, vote: electorVoteType}));
        _pollingByCandidate[candidateId].votes.totalPercentage = _calculePercentageOfVote(_pollingByCandidate[candidateId].votes.total);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a few problems in the code. It won't work. To start with:

1. You misunderstand how the contract instance is represented inside the code of other contract. It's not the object like in JS or tuple in Python.

```
struct PollingByCandidate {
    _Candidate candidate;
    _Elector[] electors;
    Vote votes;
}
```

_Candidate and _Elector are contract types.

In solidity, it is type that is stored like an address variable with little information about the contract code.
So, in places where you need the address, you use `address(variableOfContractType)`. When you need to call a function you write `variableOfContractType.functionName()` and it will compile it into the internal transaction to the contract address, with data encoded from the contract.code, to call the desired function with properly constructed arguments.

But when you print it to the console or just return, it won't return you all the data of the contract.

Simply saying, you need to return no the cotract instance, but the data you want to get from it, like

```
contract ElectronicVotingMachine {

PollingByCandidate[6] private _pollingByCandidate;

function getCandidateAvatar(uint candidateId) external view returns (string memory) {
    (uint id, string memory avatar) = _pollingByCandidate[candidateId].candidate.getInformation();
    return avatar;
}
}
```

Next noticeable problem is that you store dynamic array, which is represented in solidity as mapping with indexes, to store constracts that you want to return all at once:
`_Elector[] electors;`
in `PollingByCandidate`

It doesn't work that way, whole mapping and dynamic array represent "infinite-scale" storage and can not be stored in memory(not storage) or returned as result. Take a look [at this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68010434/why-cant-i-return-dynamic-array-in-solidity)

**EDIT:**
If you want to access this data both in other contracts and in scripts. The most elegant way is to store/return the address instead of the Contract type. And in contracts, you can cast it with `ContractName(address)` *(but I would recommend to use interfaces because it's more gas efficient)*. And in scripts, you can read the address and cast it to the contract (like with ethers.js) `new ethers .Contract( addressOrName, abi, providerOrSigner)`

Comment: The code compiles and deploys, in the main contract I can access the function using what you told me address(ELECTOR CONTRACT ADDRESS), so the only place I can't access it is outside the contract, that is, in the scripts file for deployment and testing.

So knowing that.

1) Why is it wrong if I compile and deploy and I can access the function within the contract?

2) How to access the Elector function in the scripts file, as there is no "address" function with etheres.

Comment: 1) I did't try to compile, but I am sure it won't return the data the way you wanted, with these structs and types. 

2) Actually I updated my answer with suggestion. (And in ethers.js there is a way to get the address, I think I miss what you mean)

Comment: Regarding the matrices, the way I did they were not stored in the blockchain? For example, I need that when the contract is inserted in mainet, the candidates that are there are added (id, avatar) and these data must not be changed.